# Set depth level properity in flattened object hierarchy

Tags: javascript

Given this unordered flat object array

```
var obj = [
    {
        id: 1,
        parentId: null
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        parentId: 1
    },
    ...
}];
```

I want to set a property `$level` according to the hierarchy depth level. (There is no max depth)

So the result would be

```
var obj = [
    {
        id: 1,
        parentId: null,
        $level = 0
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        parentId: 1,
        $level = 1
    },
    ...
}];
```

I was thinking of writing a recursive function for this that would traverse the array and find the matching `parentId == id` and then if that also had a parent then again find the matching... while keeping a count of how many calls it took to reach a root. But that's a lot of array iteration. It just seems bad.

So figured that this was a solved problem. But searching didn't give me anything useful. So I came here :)

How would you solve this?

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense to me. I see the object with `id=2` as also having `level=0` as it's not nested within any other objects.

Comment: @Andy it has a `parentId`, the parent is `1` which itself has a depth of 0. So `2` is a child of `1`, hence the `$level` of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there is `setLevel(parentId, level)`, a recursive function. The start values are `null` and level zero. The function has two parts. First get all rows which parentId equals to the given parentId. Then iterate throu the rows and assigns the level and calls itselft with the id as new value for parentId and a increased level.

```
var obj = [
    {
        id: 2,
        parentId: 1
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        parentId: null
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        parentId: 4
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        parentId: 2
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        parentId: 2
    },
];
function setLevel(parentId, level) {
    obj.filter(function (el) {
        return el.parentId === parentId;
    }).forEach(function (el) {
        el.$level = level;
        setLevel(el.id, level + 1);
    });
}
setLevel(null, 0);
document.write('<pre>'+ JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `obj[el.parentID - 1]`?

Comment: Unfortunately the array is unordered

Answer (score 0):

You don't have much choice for the solution in my opinion.
For each element, you have to traverse the array, searching for the number of ancestors for the element, the recursive or the iterative way.

In this case, you just search for an obj with the correct id.

You can't just call for the direct `$level` of the parent because your array is not ordered, then the parent's `$level` is not always set.

Comment: "$level is not always set" that's the exact problem. I was hoping that someone had made something smart :)